# When choosing an installer, should I require an MSI file?

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer

I'm evaluating a number of windows installer tools for our application. Some of them will create .MSI files, but some of them only create .EXEs.

I'm all for keeping up with the times, but should I make it a requirement of the app I choose that it be able to create a .MSI file? Is there any reason to require that over a simple installer .EXE?

Our software isn't intended for corporate deployment, so we don't need an MSI for that (for unattended installs etc). But if we're going to skip the MSI, I want to know what advantages I'd be missing out on.

Comment: This question isn't exactly off-topic here, but I think you'd get much better responses if you asked over on serverfault, since network administrators are the ones who are going to be in pain if you don't provide an MSI.

Comment: That's a good point, but our software is for home users, not corporate admins, so that aspect (thankfully) doesn't concern us. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at that other thread here: [What's the prime advantage to having an MSI installation package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304425/whats-the-prime-advantage-to-having-an-msi-installation-package/4304564#4304564)

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't care about MSI features like unattended install or *administrative install* you can skip MSI. On the other hand skipping MSI doesn't seem to provide any advantage. Just use the installer tool you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Use Inno Setup :-)
I've experienced unresolvable dependency issues with msi installers in the past.