# What are the pros and cons of using MSI and MSP?

Tags: asp.net, windows-installer, msp

What are the pros and cons of using MSI and MSP in using them for deployment. I was thinking of automating the deployment of my software using MSI and MSP.
I wanted to understand if there is any concerns. And also how feasible is it to use MSP for patch deployment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MSI package advantages you can go through this thread:
[What's the prime advantage to having an MSI installation package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304425/whats-the-prime-advantage-to-having-an-msi-installation-package)

Regarding MSP patches, they were designed to be applied as patches. If you follow the [patching rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367850%28VS.85%29.aspx), they work perfectly.